# Wireless adapter turning off on Sony Vaio

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-FZ140E (Windows 7) and the problem is that sudenlly the wireless adapter turns off. My drivers are updated. Does anyone knows what can be wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your power settings to see if your laptop is turning off the device to conserve power.

Comment: Checked. It is not it.